# Python: converting list of lists to tuples of tuples

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

A Python newbie! I need help converting a list of lists tuples of tuples.

I want to call the append_as_tuples function, but every time I return it, it says
it can only concatenate lists (not tuples) to lists

Here is what I have so far:

```
def append_as_tuple(t, l):
    ''' Convert list l to a tuple and append it to tuple t as a single value '''
    return t[:] + (tuple(l),)  

def convert_lists(lol):
    t = []
    if type(lol) == a or type(lol) == tuple:
        return [convert_lists(lol) for i in t]
    return append_as_tuples(lol,a)

#- test harness#

a=[range(5), range(10,20), ['hello', 'goodbye']]  
print a  
print convert_lists(a)  
print convert_lists([])
```

Comment: Your `if type(lol) == a` is quite wrong; it **appears** to work only because you have a global variable named `a` in your "test harness" and `a` is not a `type` instance ... so that test will be `False`. Without the global `a`, it would raise an exception.

Answer (score 62):

To convert `list_of_lists` to a tuple of tuples, use

```
tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 4):

there is a python built in function:
list and tuple

list( the tuple)...to conver tuple to list
tuple( the list )....to convert list to tuple

Comment: This will covert the outermost list to a tuple (or vice versa).  However, the inner lists/tuples will remain as their original type.