# Converting a list of lists to a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have got a list of lists:

```
[['AB', '132'], ['C D'], ['EFG'], ['HJ K', '2  1']]
```

and i am trying to convert it into a list of tuples:

```
[('AB', '132'), ('C D', ''), ('EFG', ''), ('HJ K', '2  1')]
```

Comment: And what are you having problems with? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is a pretty basic operation.

Comment: Related: [Python: converting list of lists to tuples of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506511/python-converting-list-of-lists-to-tuples-of-tuples).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exceedingly simple, just use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to loop over the source list and convert each element to a tuple, by directly passing the items to the [`tuple` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple):

```
>>> example = [['AB', '132'], ['C D'], ['EFG'], ['HJ K', '2 1']]
>>> [tuple(i) for i in example]
[('AB', '132'), ('C D',), ('EFG',), ('HJ K', '2 1')]
```

Alternatively, if you like functional programming, use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) instead:

```
>>> map(tuple, example)
[('AB', '132'), ('C D',), ('EFG',), ('HJ K', '2 1')]
```

Comment: don't use `l` as a variable name (see PEP-8). Change it to `L` or a new name

Comment: When writing a quick example on the command prompt I tend to ignore PEP-8; I leave that to my editor's linting plugin. :-) Still, I've changed it to `i` to prevent the idea spreading.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `map(tuple, l)`:

```
In [1]: l=[['AB', '132'], ['C D'], ['EFG'], ['HJ K', '2  1']]  

In [2]: map(tuple, l)
Out[2]: [('AB', '132'), ('C D',), ('EFG',), ('HJ K', '2  1')]
```

The downside is that in Python 3, this would return an iterable instead of a list. If you have to have a list, this will need to be spelled out as `list(map(tuple, l))` (this works in both Python 2 and 3).

Another approach that works in both Python 2 and 3 is to use a list comprehension:

```
[tuple(x) for x in l]
```

Comment: And so we all three scramble to improve our posts :-P

Comment: don't use `l` as a variable name (see PEP-8). Change it to `L` or a new name.

Comment: Why is returning an iterable a downside?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: That depends on the OP's requirements. If they specifically require a list, then returning anything other than a list simply doesn't meet the spec.

Answer (score 1):

[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will convert each element of your list into a tuple:

```
data = [['AB', '132'], ['C D'], ['EFG'], ['HJ K', '2 1']]
[tuple(elem) for elem in data]
```

gives:

```
[('AB', '132'), ('C D',), ('EFG',), ('HJ K', '2 1')]
```